# How can I iterate through an array in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function where I am iterating through the todos array. If todos has a value, return the value, else return a string saying "There are no To Dos yet!". But i am not sure if i wrote the function correctly or how i would invoke the function.

```
const todos = [
    {todo: 'Go to the gym', done: true},
    {todo: 'Cook dinner', done: false},
    {todo: 'Watch a movie', done: false}
];

todos.forEach(function(t) {
  if (todos.length === 0 ) {
    return 'There are no To Dos yet!';
  } else {
    return t.todo;
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you want to return for the given data?

Comment: the todo item if there is a value else the string there is no to dos

Comment: `forEach` iterates only if items are in the array. but what do you want to return?

Comment: what if there is only `{todo:"mything",done:true}` or it is `{todo:"",done:false}`

Comment: Do you want to return values or print values? I'm asking because you can't return a value in the forEach callback, but you could print each value `t.todo`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
const todos = [
    {todo: 'Go to the gym', done: true},
    {todo: 'Cook dinner', done: false},
    {todo: 'Watch a movie', done: false}
];

if (todos.length > 0) {
   todos.forEach(function(t) {
      console.log(t.todo);
   });
}
else {
   return 'There are no To Dos yet!';
}
```

Comment: `return t.todo` does not make sense. The callback of forEach should always return undefined ie nothing. @sahussai Do you want to print t.todo instead? `console.log(t.todo)`

Comment: @JorgeZapatero Thank you for correcting me. Yes, forEach returns "undefined". I updated my answer just to log it to console.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if every todo has been completed by using `Array.prototype.every`:

```js
const todos = [
  { todo: 'Go to the gym', done: true  },
  { todo: 'Cook dinner',   done: false },
  { todo: 'Watch a movie', done: false }
];

printTodos(todos);

todos.forEach(todo => todo.done = true); // All  done..

printTodos(todos);

function printTodos(todos) {
  return console.log(todos.every(todo => todo.done)
    ? 'There are no To-Dos yet!'
    : todos.filter(todo => !todo.done)
        .map(todo => '- ' + todo.todo)
        .join('\n'))
}
```

---

#### Simplified

Since we need to map them anyways, let's just filter them.

```js
const todos = [
  { todo: 'Go to the gym', done: true  },
  { todo: 'Cook dinner',   done: false },
  { todo: 'Watch a movie', done: false }
];

printTodos(todos);

todos.forEach(todo => todo.done = true); // All  done..

printTodos(todos);

function printTodos(todos) {
  let notCompleted = todos.filter(todo => !todo.done);
  return console.log(notCompleted.length === 0
    ? 'There are no To-Dos yet!'
    : notCompleted.map(todo => '- ' + todo.todo).join('\n'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since forEach doesn't return anything, try `.map()` which returns a transformed array.

```
const getTodos = todos => {
  const result = todos.map(({ todo }) => todo);
  return result.length ? result : "There are no todos yet";
}

getTodos(todos) // ["Go to the gym", "Cook dinner", "etc."]
getTodos([]) // "There are no todos yet"
```

If you only want todos filtered by `done` property, chain filter to it:

```
const getTodos = todos => {
  const result = todos
    .filter(todo => !todo.done)
    .map(({ todo }) => todo)

  return result.length ? result : "There are no todos yet";
}

getTodos(todos) // ["Go to the gym"]
getTodos([]) // "There are no todos yet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the `togo` array and join it to a string or return the message.

```js
const
    getTodos = todos => todos.map(({ todo }) => todo).join(', ') || 'There are no To Dos yet!',
    todos = [{ todo: 'Go to the gym', done: true }, { todo: 'Cook dinner', done: false }, { todo: 'Watch a movie', done: false }];

console.log(getTodos([]));
console.log(getTodos(todos));
```